# How can I get filename of current working cs file and the name of the current class

Tags: c#

Suppose I am working on Welcome.cs file. In the constructor I want to print "Welcome". However, If I put the same code in HelloWorld.cs, it should print HellowWorld. How do I do that?

Comment: Code files have no influence on your compiled application. You can have an application with 10.000 classes in one codefile.

Comment: Do you want the name of the **file** or the **class**? They are fundamentally different and anything they have in common is only by convention.

Comment: @J.Steen: Actually the class name.

Comment: @TimSchmelter there are Framework methods for doing this now, so I think it's ok to keep this question

Answer (score 14):

You can try

```
string thisFile = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0).GetFileName();
```

Comment: This is the way to do it.  Note that the `true` means include debug information.  This only works on a debug build, which emits the `pdb` file containing source information.

Comment: This is the way to do it if OP hadn't been confused. =)

Comment: @harpo So this wouldn't work in production build?

Answer (score 11):

if I've understood correctly, try `this.GetType().Name`

Comment: One of us hasn't understood correctly.  The OP asked how to get the source file name.

Comment: @harpo - just read his comment - seems he did mean class

Comment: Yes I mean the class name. I got the answer. Thanx buddy

Answer (score 11):

How to print

[**current file name** - **method name** - **line number**] ?

```
private static void Log(string text,
                        [CallerFilePath] string file = "",
                        [CallerMemberName] string member = "",
                        [CallerLineNumber] int line = 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}_{1}({2}): {3}", Path.GetFileName(file), member, line, text);
}
```

Test:

```
Log("Test");
```

Output:

> Program.cs_Main(11): Test

Answer (score 8):

Try this to get the file name:

```
string currentFile = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0).GetFileName();
```

To get the current line:

```
int currentLine = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the class name, you can use Reflection technique.

eg:

```
Type classType = yourObject.GetType();
```

you can get the name of the class from

classType.Name

Comment: Great answer, but unfortunately this answer is already present.